# Prove/disprove: There isn't any graph with an even number of vertices and an odd number of edges that contains Euler's circuit.

Tags: combinatorics

> Prove/disprove: There isn't any graph with an even number of vertices and an odd number of edges that contains Euler's circuit.

I immediately looked at the theorem: "A ***connected*** graph has an Euler's circuit if and only if all the degrees of the vertices are even."

But here I wasn't given that it is connected. So perhaps we can say that the following graph has an euler's circut? Because it visits each edge exactly once and comes back to the same vertix:

> My proposition: 6 vertices. 3 on that have no neighbours. and the other 3 that form a triangle. Assume that the vertices names that create a triangle are $v_1, v_2, v_3$ then the path $v_1 -> v_2 -> v_3 -> v_1$ is an Euler's circut. That is a graph with 6 vertices (even) and 3 edges (odd).

Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, if the graph is connected, you can easily prove the proposition, but if it isn't, your example is correct. Now you have to see if the man who wrote the proposition just forgot the word "connected" or if he is expecting a disconnected example as yours...

Comment: I believe the question is implicitly assuming that the graph is connected. An even simpler counterexample would be a triangle together with one further disconnected vertex.

Comment: Haha, Tom, that's my professors problem.

Comment: You're correct. The definition of an Euler circuit makes no mention of connectedness; as long as there's a cycle in a graph that contains every every edge, it's Eulerian. It's only the theorem you stated that requires connectedness, not the definition.

Comment: I dealt with the two cases in case the professor just did a mistake. I proved the case when it is connected using the theorem, if we have an even number of vertices, odd number of edges, and its connected, then surely there is a vertix with an odd degree.